# Is it possible to run a client behind an onion address?

Tags: clients, nodes, privacy, tor

It is possible to run a bitcoin client which only connects to onion nodes in the TOR network, like that:

```
./bitcoind -onion=127.0.0.1:9050 -onlynet=tor -externalip=ssapp53tmftyjmjb.onion
```

Is something similar available for Ethereum?

Comment: according to an old TODO list it's planned but not yet implemented : https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/6 . Just for the sake of curiosity, what's the interest of running a client behind an onion besides the "privacy" features they grant ?

Comment: euri10 nice find

Comment: (Note: Someone has recently flagged this as off-topic. IMO it's on-topic.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, however Ethereum have developer The Whisper Protocol https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Whisper have a read through, you may find it helpful in the absence of Tor availability.