# Install and use Parity in Tails

Tags: mist, parity, installation, tor

I'm trying to install Parity.

What i did is run:

```
sudo dpkg -i Ethereum.deb
```

And it suppose to be installed, but when I run:

```
sudo parity
```

It says:

> unable to execute /usr/bin/parity No such file or directory

When I search Parity on computer it finds it in `bin` folder.

So what to do?

Comment: try 'which parity'

Answer (score 1):

1. Parity and Mist [do not work](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1904/87) in tails as they are [not able to connect via Tor](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1632/87). Be careful with that.
2. Do not put `sudo` before each command you run unless you really need to. Parity should work well without.
3. If you really need parity for some reason, install it [from source](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Setup).